# How can I intercept the HTML from a ViewResult, modify it and serve it up?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing a simple CMS.

I want to be able to load a View, having it included inside a master page, and then scan the HTML so that I can replace some custom tags (like {{blog}} with my own blog output) and then serve it up to the browser.

How can I get access to the HTML from the ViewResult in order to intercept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to write an `ActionFilterAttribute`.  This attribute has the following methods:

- **OnActionExecuting** - called just before the decorated action is executed
- **OnActionExecuted** - called after the action method is called, but before the `ActionResult` is rendered.
- **OnResultExecuting** - callled before the result is rendered
- **OnResultExecuted** - called after the result is rendered

There is an example here which returns either JSON or XML data depending on the "Content-type" header: [Create REST API using ASP.NET MVC that speaks both Json and plain Xml](http://omaralzabir.com/create_rest_api_using_asp_net_mvc_that_speaks_both_json_and_plain_xml/)

Comment: The link in this answer has gone dead :-(

Comment: I've corrected the link to go to what I think was the original source article.

Answer (score 4):

That's going to be tricky because the ViewResult writes its response directly to the Response.Stream. So you'll probably have to deal with the Response.Filter property to output the ViewResult to a MemoryStream so you can manipulate the content before returning a ContentResult. All this would happen in OnResultExecuting probably.

Comment: Sorry, my initial question lead us down the garden path. I really just awnt to be able to do some replacement on tags in the View and serve that up. I was being presumptuous in returning a ContentResult.