# Is it possible to modify the output of the razor viewengine just before sending it to the client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Im building an ASP.NET MVC 3 app using Razor as template language.

Here is what I would like to do:
When all template content from cshtml-files for a certain request have been parsed in razor viewengine and ready to output to the visitor - then I would like to insert some extra information into the parsed html content.

So my question is:
Is there an event of any kind to hook on to inside the Razor viewengine or inside the MVC framework that allows me to do this kind of changes to the output?

Don't ask why I'd want to do something like this in a MVC application, it's a long and boring story.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the generated html after razor has rendered it? If so can you just modify the cshtml file instead? if not it can be done but not recommended.

Comment: I know it's not recommended but I sadly need to and modifying the cshtml is to late in the "cycle".
Anyway.. Do you have any suggestions as to how to do it?

Comment: If that's the case please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642148/how-to-intercept-view-rendering-to-add-html-js-on-all-partial-views

Comment: That is just a brilliant idea!
As far as I can see I could use that overload and inject raw html on the "CreateView" method wich contains the raw html of a request with a masterpage. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Given the vagueness of your question, perhaps this article might help, or maybe you can specify in what way the article isn't helpful...

[Dependency Injection in ASP.Net MVC Views](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/19/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-views/)

UPDATE:

How about an ActionFilter? I seem to recall that you can get the viewresult and tinker with it in an ActionFilter, although I have only ever done this for a json transformation. Here's another article: [Use ASP.Net action filters to render](http://jesschadwick.blogspot.com/2008/07/use-aspnet-mvc-actionfilters-to-render_02.html)

Here's a [SO answer--this might be a duplicate question!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/203850/1284283)

Comment: The problem, as far as I can see, with that article is that it does not expose any method of injecting into the output at the point in the rendering cycle where all content has been rendered. The Render method in the article example will be executed for each view.What I'm looking for is a method of doing injections of data into the output when Im certain all content has been rendered.

Comment: And for your special case, you want to do this before it leaves the server, and it absolutely cannot be done in the view itself?

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you can get to the view result in an action filter. I remember doing this for json output (to transform a "normal" c# object into a hungarian-notation-horrible datatables json object. In a similar way, you may be able to get the raw html output and manipulate it.

Comment: That particular example link doesn't allow for altering the view only providing a different result based on some rules and returning a new result.

Comment: @brightgarden: But wont that raw html only contain the output of the specific view connected to the actionresult? Or will, for example, the layout page be inside the raw html output in filterContext.GetViewData()?

Comment: If you had a way to dynamically modify something that is currently in your _layout.cshtml, would that solve your problem?

Comment: @brightgarden As I write before, the modification of the output needs to be done when layout, page, partials and sections have been rendered. So any modification of the layout template done before that is to early in the cycle. BuildStarted gave me pointers to solution that works in his comment on my original post, using a custom viewengine.